# Proving Existence of Infimum of Functional of Riemannian Metric

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $(\Sigma, g_0)$ be a closed, oriented surface with a Riemannian metric satisfying $\int_\Sigma dA_0 = 1$, where $dA_0$ is the area form on $\Sigma$, and let $\nabla_0$ and $K_0$ denote the gradient and the Gaussian curvature of $(\Sigma, g_0)$, respectively. Consider all the metrics conformal to $g_0$ that preserve the area, i.e., all metrics of the form
\begin{equation*}
\{e^{2\varphi} g_0: \varphi \in C^\infty(M)\}
\end{equation*}
such that
\begin{equation*}
\int_\Sigma e^{2\varphi} \, dA_0 = 1,
\end{equation*}
and define the following functional $F(\varphi)$ on the set of all such area-preserving conformal metrics:
\begin{equation*}
                F(\varphi) = \frac{1}{2}\int_\Sigma |\nabla_0 \varphi|^2 \, dA_0 + \int_\Sigma K_0 \varphi \, dA_0 - \pi \chi(\Sigma) \log\left(\int_\Sigma e^{2\varphi} dA_0\right).
            \end{equation*}
My question is: For the case $\chi(\Sigma) \leq 0$, how do we show that $F$ is bounded from below?

For context, this functional is from the following paper that involves extremizing a functional of the metric on a Riemannian manifold and, in particular, I'm trying to understand why the infimum of $F$ exists:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123688900705